# Framming trimmed circle view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI (worked with UIKit before), and I got this internal, learning/testing project to do, and I ran into this problem.
I have two trimmed circles in a ZStack (and those two texts), in a HStack so I can add that little icon on its right side. How can I trim that bottom, invisible part of the circles so it fits my needs because it pushes everything down?

Edit: I tried clipping and padding with EdgeInsets, but still, changing the frame size pushes everything around. I'm looking for a proper way of doing this, and not some "hack".

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D996.png)

```
private struct ActivityCircleComponent: View {
    
    private let widthOfCircle: CGFloat = 15
    private let headerIconSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.03
    private let rotationAmount: Double = 152.5
    private let progress: Double = 0.4
    private let trimAmount: CGFloat = 40
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                ZStack {
                    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.65)
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.widthOfCircle, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.rotationAmount))
                        
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0.0, to: self.progress)
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.widthOfCircle, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.rotationAmount))
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .top, .trailing], self.widthOfCircle / 2)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("10.000")
                            .font(Fonts.Roboto.bold.of(size: 30))
                        
                        Text("meters")
                            .font(Fonts.Roboto.light.of(size: 20))
                    }
                }
                
                Image("Goal")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: self.headerIconSize)
            }
            .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

PS Don't mind the state of the code, I'm just playing around

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The problem you are encountering is that the `Circle()` is all still there, you are just hiding part. Your better solution to this issue is to draw a path, not use a trimmed shape. Arcs are simple to draw. See: [Paths vs shapes in SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/paths-vs-shapes-in-swiftui). Paul even shows how to draw an arc there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with drawing a custom path in SwiftUI, and it's a bit more work than I should put into this. That's why I tried to avoid it. I guess I'll need to do it that way.
Thanks for the warm welcome!

PS Paul Hudson is the best

Comment: Did you read the link? He gives you a struct that returns an arc shape that you could drop in instead of a circle. I am not sure the extra work here...

Comment: Because it’s drawn from left to right, and starting point is on the right. When I’m drawing the arc on top I need to calculate the total length of arc underneath, calculate the length of the arc on top, and angle where it should stop. It took me about 15ish mins to settle everything in, but its 10 mins more than using circles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would use the link I provided in my comment. I used `.overlay` instead of `ZStack` as you get one view that you don't have to worry about tweaking things when your screen size changes. Easy peasy:

```
struct ActivityCircleComponent: View {

    private let widthOfCircle: CGFloat = 15
    private let headerIconSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.03
    private let progress: Double = 0.4
    private let trimAmount: CGFloat = 40

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Arc(startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(220), clockwise: true)
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: widthOfCircle, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 120)
            .fixedSize()
            .overlay(
                Arc(startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(progress * 220), clockwise: true)
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: widthOfCircle, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 120)
                    .fixedSize()
            )
            
            Image(systemName: "rosette")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: self.headerIconSize)

        }
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Text("10.000")
                
                Text("meters")
            }
        )
    }

}

struct Arc: Shape {
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    var clockwise: Bool

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let rotationAdjustment = Angle.degrees(200)
        let modifiedStart = startAngle - rotationAdjustment
        let modifiedEnd = endAngle - rotationAdjustment

        var path = Path()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.width / 2, startAngle: modifiedStart, endAngle: modifiedEnd, clockwise: !clockwise)

        return path
    }
}
```